# GEKKO knapsack Optimization can't reach the right result

Tags: python, optimization, knapsack-problem, gekko

Trying to use GEKKO to solve knapsack optimization problem, but can't reach a satisfactory result.
I have input data:

```
input_data = '30 100000\n90000 90001\n89750 89751\n10001 10002\n89500 89501\n10252 10254\n89250 89251\n10503 10506\n89000 89001\n10754 10758\n88750 88751\n11005 11010\n88500 88501\n11256 11262\n88250 88251\n11507 11514\n88000 88001\n11758 11766\n87750 87751\n12009 12018\n87500 87501\n12260 12270\n87250 87251\n12511 12522\n87000 87001\n12762 12774\n86750 86751\n13013 13026\n86500 86501\n13264 13278\n86250 86251\n'
```

I found one solution example on https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/KnapsackOptimization

```
from gekko import GEKKO

# parse the input
lines = input_data.split('\n')
firstLine = lines[0].split()
item_count = int(firstLine[0])
capacity = int(firstLine[1])

v = []
w = []

for i in range(1, item_count+1):
    line = lines[i]
    parts = line.split()
    v.append(int(parts[0])) 
    w.append(int(parts[1]))
    
# Create model
m = GEKKO(remote = False)
x = m.Array(m.Var,item_count,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
m.Maximize(m.sum([v[i]*x[i] for i in range(item_count)]))    
m.Equation(m.sum([w[i]*x[i] for i in range(item_count)]) <= capacity)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

value = int((m.options.objfcnval)*-1)
taken = []

for i in range(item_count):
    taken.append(int(x[i].value[0]))
```

I got the following results:

```
value
>>> 99998
str(taken)
>>> '[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]'
```

But the optimal result is:

```
>>> 99798
>>> '[0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]'
```

Please kindly help me to understand how to make GEKKO solver do the job properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increasing the solver tolerance.

```py
m.options.RTOL = 1e-10
m.options.OTOL = 1e-10

m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-5',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10000',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1e-8']
```

The solution takes longer but gives the correct solution.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

input_data = '30 100000\n90000 90001\n89750 89751\n10001 10002\n89500 89501\n10252 10254\n89250 89251\n10503 10506\n89000 89001\n10754 10758\n88750 88751\n11005 11010\n88500 88501\n11256 11262\n88250 88251\n11507 11514\n88000 88001\n11758 11766\n87750 87751\n12009 12018\n87500 87501\n12260 12270\n87250 87251\n12511 12522\n87000 87001\n12762 12774\n86750 86751\n13013 13026\n86500 86501\n13264 13278\n86250 86251\n'

# parse the input
lines = input_data.split('\n')
firstLine = lines[0].split()
item_count = int(firstLine[0])
capacity = int(firstLine[1])

v = []
w = []

for i in range(1, item_count+1):
    line = lines[i]
    parts = line.split()
    v.append(int(parts[0])) 
    w.append(int(parts[1]))

print('v: ')
print(v[0:3])
print('w: ')
print(w[0:3])
print('capacity:')
print(capacity)
# Create model
m = GEKKO(remote = False)

m.options.RTOL = 1e-10
m.options.OTOL = 1e-10

m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-5',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10000',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1e-8']

x = m.Array(m.Var,item_count,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)

#sol1 = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
#sol2 = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
#for i,xi in enumerate(x):
#    xi.value = sol1[i]
m.Maximize(m.sum([v[i]*x[i] for i in range(item_count)]))
s = m.Var()
m.Equation(s==m.sum([w[i]*x[i] for i in range(item_count)]))
m.Equation(s <= capacity)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

value = int((m.options.objfcnval)*-1)
taken = []

for i in range(item_count):
    taken.append(int(x[i].value[0]))

print(taken)
print(s.value[0])
```